# How to loop through a file using input from another file

Tags: shell, for-loop, grep

I have a `.csv` file of character strings (about 5,400) that appear, in addition to many other strings, in a large `.txt` file of a huge corpus. I need to count the occurrences of each one of the 5,400 strings in the `.txt` corpus file. I'm using the shell (I have a Macbook Pro) and I don't know how to write a for loop with an input from one file to then work in another file. The `input_file.csv` looks like this:

```
A_back
A_bill
A_boy
A_businessman
A_caress
A_chat
A_con
A_concur
A_cool
A_cousin
A_discredit
A_doctor
A_drone_AP_on
A_fellow
A_flatter
A_friend
A_gay
A_giddy
A_guilty
A_harangue
A_ignore
A_indulge
A_interested
A_kind
A_laugh
A_laugh_AP_at
...
```

The `corpus_file.txt` I'm searching through is a cleaned and lemmatized corpus with one sentence per line; this is 4 lines of the text:

```
A_recently N_pennsylvania N_state_N_university V_launch a N_program that V_pay A_black N_student AP_for V_improve their N_grade a N_c AP_to N_c A_average V_bring 550 and N_anything A_high V_bring 1,100
A_here V_be the N_sort AP_of A_guilty N_kindness that V_kill
what N_kind AP_of N_self_N_respect V_be a A_black N_student V_go AP_to V_have AP_as PR_he or PR_she V_reach AP_out AP_to V_take 550 AP_for N_c N_work A_when A_many A_white N_student V_would V_be V_embarrass AP_by A_so A_average a N_performance
A_white N_student V_would V_be V_embarrass AP_by A_so A_average a N_performance
```

I am looking to count exactly how many times each of the strings in `input_file.csv` appear in `corpus_file.txt`. I can do one at a time with the following code:

```
grep -c A_guilty corpus_file.txt
```

And in a few seconds I get a count of how many times `A_guilty` appears in `corpus_file.txt` (it appears once in the bit of the corpus I have put here). However, I don't want to do that 5,400 times, so I'm trying to put it into a loop that will output each character string and its count.

I have tried to run the code below:

```
for input_file.csv in directory/path/folder/ do grep -c corpus_file.txt done
```

But it doesn't work. `input_file.csv` and `corpus_file.txt` are both in the same folder so have the same directory.

I'm hoping to end up with a list of the 5,400 character strings and the number of times each string appears in the large `corpus_file.txt` file. Something like this:

```
term - count
A_back - 2093
A_bill - 873
A_boy - 1877
A_businessman - 148
A_caress - 97
A_chat - 208
A_con - 633
```

Comment: not sure this will give you the exact results you want, but try `grep -cFf corpus_file.txt input_file.txt`. (`man grep`). It may help if you sort or `corpus` file first. `sort -o corpus_file.txt corpus_file.txt`. Good luck.

Comment: [edit] your question to show an example of the corpus file you want to search for those strings in and the expected output given those 2 input files. We can't help you write a script to parse a file looking for strings if we don't know what the file looks like. make sure to include partial match cases (e.g. if `the` is in your file of words and `there` appears in your corpus file should `the` be counted as having matched? - rhetorical question, cover it in your [mcve]).

Comment: Please revisit your example to make sure that the expected output you provide is the exact output expected given the sample input you provided, not some other output that could be produced from some other input as the latter is not nearly as useful in helping us understand your requirements and definitely not when it comes to testing if a possible solution works or not! See [ask] and in particular the part about providing a [mcve] if that's not clear.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This might be all you need:

```
$ cat words
sweet_talk
white_man
hispanic_american

$ cat corpus
foo
sweet_talk
bar
hispanic_american
sweet_talk

$ grep -Fowf words corpus | sort | uniq -c
      1 hispanic_american
      2 sweet_talk
```

If not then edit your question to clarify your requirements and provide more truly representative sample input/output.

Comment: Thanks for replying; I edited my question, hopefully it's clearer now.